# Deadlock on reading file in Release mode

Tags: c#, uwp

When i'm trying to open file from local storage in release mode, thread locks on `GetFileAsync`. In Debug everything works great

Target Windows version is 1809, min - 1803

```
var localStorage = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await localStorage.GetFileAsync(_configPath);

using (var str = (await file.OpenReadAsync()).AsStream())
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
    return (Config)serializer.Deserialize(str);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of _configPath. Can you enable .NET Native understand debug mode to see what error it reports? Do you have a simple, reproduceable demo which you can provide to us?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT `private const string _configPath = "config.xml"`, there is no exception is beeing thrown, thread just locks on this function.

Comment: OK. I tested your app and I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you enable .NET Native and see if you can reproduce your issue under debug mode? Can you aslo provide a demo?